# what is this command in c# "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\vsjitdebugger.exe -p %ld -e %ld -g %ld\"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i came across this command,
i want to know what this command for, and what are the options for?
i am looking for brief introduction & any source links for basic explanation.

Thanks,

Comment: Please give more info on what you are trying to do.  How is this question getting upvotes?

Comment: i am trying to understand somebody else's code. i just want to   know about this command in technical terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VSJITDEBUGGER` is the Visual Studio Just-in-time debugger. The command you're seeing in your source code is attempting to run it with some specific arguments:

```
vsjitdebugger
    -p <processId>
    -e <??>
    -g <??>
```

I don't know what the `-e` and `-g` arguments are for, I've never used them. The `-p` specifies a process ID to attach the debugger to.

The `"%ld"` sections of the string are printf-formatting so you can insert the process ID (and other arguments) before running the command.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a C# command is just a windows program.
Specifically is the Visual Studio Just In time Debugger. The -p %ld -e %ld -g %ld are arguments that are passed to this program.

Run vsjitdebugger.exe /? to understand what this arguments are.
Google the program name(sdjitdebugger.exe) if  you need more info.